# How to switch() on Drawable in android

Tags: android, android-drawable

So I can create a Drawable from a resource like this:

```
adrawable = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.person)
```

But how do I get the id of the resource back from the Drawable, so that I can do a switch on it?

```
switch (adrawable) { // This throws an error

}
```

Comment: I need to know what image is displayed by the Drawable...

Comment: I've look through the documentation and can't seem to find anything: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html

Comment: A drawable does not keep a reference to the ID from which it was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
adrawable = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.person)
for(int id : adrawable.getState()){
    switch (id) {
        case ...: //use the id you try to look for
            ... //execute if case is true
        break;

        ...

        default:
            ...
    }
}
```